# How can I improve the range of an XBee S6B?

Tags: wifi

Has anyone used the XBee WiFI modules? Done a range check on them?

With my laptop i get a range of around 400m on industrial level Accesspoints on a football field, well how good are these devices ? If i get a SMA Connector version and use a higher gain antenna am I looking at ranges from 250-500m ? (Talking 18-22dBi gains here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends whether you're talking Point to point or just in a wifi field. According to the [datasheet](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/ds_xbeewifis6b.pdf) the transmit power is +16dBm or 40 mW and a maximum sensitivity of -93dBm. According to [my favorite link budget calculator](http://www.afar.net/rf-link-budget-calculator/) with 2 of these modules both with 22dBi gain antennas on them you will get around 6 miles (RF line of sight) out of them with a respectable 33dB fade margin. But I suspect you are asking about accessing a standard wifi router, and with a receiving antenna gain of 0dBi (perfictaly omnidirectional) and a sensitivity of -70dBm (crappy ap) you will have a fade margin of around 13dB which would work, and I suspect it would be higher. So, those modules should work for your application, but the best way to find out is to test them.